# DensityPlot: giving the same color to a range of values

Tags: plotting, color

The following command

```
DensityPlot[x y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> {"Rainbow"}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

gives the following output:

[image: Densityplot1].

I know that I can change the scale of the coloring in DensityPlot using PlotRange. I.e., the following command

```
DensityPlot[x y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> {"Rainbow"}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 1}}]
```

gives the following output:

[image: DensityPlot2]

In the second plot, the red color is assigned to the value $1$ and the purple color to the value $-1$. 
**Question**: is there a way to change the colors in the DensityPlot such that such that the red color is assigned to **all** values $\geq 1$, and similarly the purple color to $\leq 1$? So basically, I would like to obtain the second plot, where the four white corners are then colored red (upper left & lower right) or purple (upper right & lower left).

(Actually I'm using ListDensityPlot instead of DensityPlot, but I'm assuming this is similar.)

Comment: Look up `Clip[]` and the option setting `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `ClippingStyle` is better suited to what he's asking for.

Comment: @rcollyer, forgot that option! Thanks for putting up an answer; what I had in mind was `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, Clip[(* stuff *)]]`, and yours is certainly more idiomatic.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I have to get that silver badge, eventually. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`ClippingStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClippingStyle.html) which accepts an arguments of the form

```
{gmin, gmax}
```

where `gmin` (`gmax`) is displayed for the lower (upper) clipped region. To match the colors exactly, you want to use [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html), e.g.

```
ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}] /@ {-1, 1}
```

where I used the form allowing you to specify the range which I did for visual consistency. Of course, you could just use

```
ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ {0, 1}
```

regardless of range.

```
DensityPlot[x y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> {"Rainbow"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 1}}, 
 ClippingStyle -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}] /@ {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks! I was told once I should wait a bit in case a superior answer somehow appears, remind me if I forget to accept your answer in a day :P

Comment: Increasing the `PlotPoints` (say `PlotPoints -> 100`) gives a smoother plot.